# dynamic type casting in parameter in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

I happen to see a code something like this.

```
function((dynamic) param1, param2);
```

When and why do we need this kind of dynamic type casting for parameters?

Comment: I'd like to see more. Generally, if the function takes a dynamic variable you *could* cast, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @scottm: That's what i was thinking initially, then I remembered you can also use it to choose the correct overload of a method at run-time.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Very small use case. This is the kind of thing I would be scolding a previous developer for using intentionally.

Comment: @scottm: Don't mistake my answer as an endorsement of the practice :-) I'm not saying its right or wrong or good or bad, just that it's one way you can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be used to dynamically choose an overload of `function(...)` based on the type of `param1` at runtime, for example:

```
public static void Something(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

public static void Something(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
}
public static void Main()
{
    object x = "A String";

    // This will choose string overload of Something() and output "Hello"
    Something((dynamic)x);

    x = 13;

    // This will choose int overload of Something() and output "Goodbye"
    Something((dynamic)x);
}
```

So even though `x` is a reference to `object`, it will decide at runtime what overload of `Something()` to call.  Note that if there is no appropriate overload, an exception will be thrown:

```
    // ...
    x = 3.14;

    // No overload of Something(double) exists, so this throws at runtime.
    Something((dynamic)x);
```